# Is there a way to compile a bunch of C source code one by one with a Makefile?

Tags: c, makefile

I have created a Makefile along with some C source code files and a header file (.h).

```
NAME = libft.a

SRCS = ft_isalnum.c ft_isalpha.c ft_isascii.c ft_isdigit.c ft_isprint.c ft_strlen.c ft_bzero.c ft_memcpy.c ft_memset.c ft_memmove.c ft_strlcpy.c ft_strlcat.c ft_toupper.c ft_tolower.c ft_strchr.c ft_strrchr.c ft_strncmp.c ft_memchr.c ft_memcmp.c ft_strnstr.c ft_atoi.c ft_calloc.c ft_strdup.c ft_substr.c ft_strjoin.c ft_strtrim.c ft_split.c ft_itoa.c ft_strmapi.c ft_striteri.c ft_putchar_fd.c ft_putstr_fd.c ft_putendl_fd.c ft_putnbr_fd.c

SRC_BONUS = ft_lstnew.c ft_lstadd_front.c ft_lstsize.c ft_lstlast.c ft_lstadd_back.c ft_lstdelone.c ft_lstclear.c ft_lstiter.c ft_lstmap.c

OBJECTS = $(SRCS:.c=.o)

OBJ_BONUS = $(SRC_BONUS:.c=.o)

CFLAGS = -Wall -Wextra -Werror

all: $(NAME)

$(NAME): $(OBJECTS)
        ar rc $(NAME) $(OBJECTS)

$(OBJECTS): $(SRCS)
        gcc $(CFLAGS) -c $(SRCS)

$(OBJ_BONUS): $(SRCS) $(SRC_BONUS)
        gcc $(CFLAGS) -c $(SRCS) $(SRC_BONUS)

bonus: $(OBJECTS) $(OBJ_BONUS)
        ar rc $(NAME) $(OBJECTS) $(OBJ_BONUS)
```

I have to create object files with those C source code files, then use those object files o create a static library (.a).

***So, I was wondering if there is a way to compile each source code file one by one instead of compiling all of those files in one step?***

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -c ft_isalnum.c ft_isalpha.c ft_isascii.c ft_isdigit.c ft_isprint.c ft_strlen.c ft_bzero.c ft_memcpy.c ft_memset.c ft_memmove.c ft_strlcpy.c ft_strlcat.c ft_toupper.c ft_tolower.c ft_strchr.c ft_strrchr.c ft_strncmp.c ft_memchr.c ft_memcmp.c ft_strnstr.c ft_atoi.c ft_calloc.c ft_strdup.c ft_substr.c ft_strjoin.c ft_strtrim.c ft_split.c ft_itoa.c ft_strmapi.c ft_striteri.c ft_putchar_fd.c ft_putstr_fd.c ft_putendl_fd.c ft_putnbr_fd.c
```

***Is the same exact thing to compile every source code file at once or doing it one by one?***

This obviusly cannot happen with the library, I need just one static library to have all those functions, so I must use all object files to create it.

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -c ft_isalnum.c ft_isalpha.c ft_isascii.c ft_isdigit.c ft_isprint.c ft_strlen.c ft_bzero.c ft_memcpy.c ft_memset.c ft_memmove.c ft_strlcpy.c ft_strlcat.c ft_toupper.c ft_tolower.c ft_strchr.c ft_strrchr.c ft_strncmp.c ft_memchr.c ft_memcmp.c ft_strnstr.c ft_atoi.c ft_calloc.c ft_strdup.c ft_substr.c ft_strjoin.c ft_strtrim.c ft_split.c ft_itoa.c ft_strmapi.c ft_striteri.c ft_putchar_fd.c ft_putstr_fd.c ft_putendl_fd.c ft_putnbr_fd.c
```

Comment: good luck with the cursus ! :) I learned C at 42 too. Be careful since The Norm does not allow the use of wildcard as the answer posted. Keep SRC as you have it, or use \ to skip newlines when writing the source file names so you have one name per line.

Comment: Thank you! I was just trying to implement new concepts in my projects with Makefile, since it has a lot of uses and it is very versatile. Anyway, it seems like I will have to restrict myself with the Norm as I we always do, hahaha :).

(IN SPANISH:Muchas gracias!. Soy de 42 Urduliz y he empezado hace poco a usar Stack Overflow, estaba encontrando nuevas ideas para mejorar mi Makefile, la Norma como siempre nos prohibe hacer cosas como estas, te agradezco que me hayas informado que el uso de wildcard esta prohibido ya que lo podria haber usado,)

Comment: Haces bien en empezar a preguntar en SO. Es importante que los nuevos desarrolladores la usemos antes que sitios privados como slack, primero porque te obliga a ser riguroso a la hora de preguntar, segundo porque luego el conocimiento se mantiene público al alcance de todos. Suerte con el cursus y a disfrutar !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is possible.

With something like this

```
SRC += $(wildcard src/*.c)

OBJECTS += $(SRC:%.c=%.o)

INCLUDE += -Iinclude

NAME = test

binary: $(OBJECTS)
    gcc -o $(NAME) $(OBJECTS)

%.o: %.c
    gcc -o $@ -c $< $(INCLUDE)
```

You have to adapt this to your makefile of course.

The key part is the last target which is executed for each *.o (and each *.o depends on its *.c file, so this *.o will only be compiled when it's older than the *.c file).
The output from a call to that makefile in a project with two files `main.c` and `other.c` could look like this:

```
>$ make binary 
gcc -o src/other.o -c src/other.c -Iinclude
gcc -o src/main.o -c src/main.c -Iinclude
gcc -o test src/other.o src/main.o
```

You can find some tips that might be helpful for you here:
http://nuclear.mutantstargoat.com/articles/make/

### PS:

I'd suggest using source and include directories (commonly "src" and "include") and an output directory ("build" or "out" are common here). Makes your life and makefile easier.

Answer (score 0):

A solution using [CMake](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/guide/tutorial/A%20Basic%20Starting%20Point.html):

First, create a CMakeLists.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required ( VERSION 3.10 )
project ( MyWonderfulProject )
file ( GLOB MySources *.c )
add_library ( MyWonderfulProject STATIC ${MySources} )
```

Then create a build directory:

```
$ mkdir build
$ cd build
```

Then create a Makefile from CMake directives and compile:

```
$ cmake ..
$ make
```

*Et voila!*